# How do I validate coordinates in my Rails model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, geolocation

I have built a Rails app that uses the HTML5 Geolocation API to get a user's current position. I use the coordinates to populate a field in my form. I want to know how to validate this in my model. Here is what my form input looks like:

```
<%= f.input :start_point, label: false,  input_html: { id: 'coordinatesStart' } %>
```

Coordinates should be i the form `54.678, 45.789` and can take any amount of numbers after the decimal point.

Any ideas how I could do this?

Comment: Do you store longitude and latitude as floats or is `start_point` a string like this `"54.678, 45.789"`?

Comment: @spickermann `start_point` is a string

Answer (score 0):

I can't run it now but try:

```
  validates :points, format: { with: /\d{1,}\.\d{1,},\s\d{1,}\.\d{1,}/, message: "please enter co-ordinates in correct format"}
```

The logic being:

Match at least 1 number, followed by a decimal, followed by 1 or more numbers, followed by a comma, followed by a space, followed by one or more numbers, followed by a a decimal, followed by one or more numbers

Comment: `99.99, 999.99` will be valid with this regex

Comment: I didn't realise that was supposed to be invalid? Just add in the upper limit for the range as required

Comment: /\d{1,2}\.\d{1,},\s\d{1,2}\.\d{1,}/ in that case

Comment: `99.99, 56.12` will be valid in this case and `85.99, 178.81` will be invalid

Comment: Are we just going to keep on inventing new rules for me to solve? :)

Comment: No new rules. These are geocoordinates and your regex is not good.

Comment: The requirements were: Coordinates should be i the form 54.678, 45.789 and can take any amount of numbers after the decimal point.
Nobody mentioned anything about the size of the numbers before the point.

Answer (score 0):

The latitude must be a number between -90 and 90 and the longitude between -180 and 180.

So in your model:

```
GEOCOORDINATES_REGEX = /\A-?(?:90(?:(?:\.0*)?)|(?:[0-9]|[1-8][0-9])(?:(?:\.\d*)?)),\s-?(?:180(?:(?:\.0*)?)|(?:[0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-7][0-9])(?:(?:\.\d*)?))\z/.freeze

validates :start_point, format: { with: GEOCOORDINATES_REGEX }
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing should be to separate input validation from model stuff. Use some separate layer, even if it's just a bare class implementing ActiveModel::Validations.

Then, add a stand-alone validator class like:

```
class GeoPairValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator
  RE = /\A\d+\.\d+, ?\d+\.\d+\z/

  def validate_each(record, attribute, value)
    # value should be "nn.nnnnnnn, nn.nnnnnnn"
    record.errors.add(attribute, :invalid, value: value) if value.to_s !~ RE

    # split by comma, convert to float
    v1, v2 = value.to_s.split(', ').map(&:to_f)

    # check logical bounds
    record.errors.add(attribute, :invalid, value: value) if v1.abs > 90
    record.errors.add(attribute, :invalid, value: value) if v2.abs > 180
  end
end
```

Finally, use it in your input class:

```
class YourInput
  include ActiveModel::Validations

  attr_accessor :start_point

  validates :start_point, geo_point: true
end
```

Also check https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Validations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-validates for more detailed information.